# обновить в базе данных max_length. django

Tags: django, postgresql

есть такой файл миграции

```
class Migration(migrations.Migration):
    dependencies = [
        ('finance', '0037_auto_20210129_1223'),
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.RunSQL("""
update finance_counterparty

"""),
        migrations.RunSQL("""
update finance_counterparty

"""),
        migrations.AlterField(
            model_name='counterparty',
            name='first_name',
            field=models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=128, verbose_name='First name'),
        ),
        migrations.AlterField(
            model_name='counterparty',
            name='last_name',
            field=models.CharField(default='', max_length=50, verbose_name='Last name'),
        ),
    ]
```

в модели я изменил max_length (раньше было 150, теперь 128 и 50) и мне нужно обновить таблицу finance_counterparty. какой запрос в RunSQL нужно прописать?

Comment: просто выполните команды `python manage.py makemigrations` и `python manage.py migrate`

Comment: получаю ошибку django.db.utils.DataError: value too long for type character varying(128)

Comment: возможно у вас есть значения который на данный момент больше 128 символов?

Comment: да, эти значения есть, в этом и состоит задача обрезать их, тоесть сделать запрос update нужно